# How to dump entire file content while sending mail?

Tags: java

I have a application, which accepts xml files, upon uploading a invalid xml file it sends a mail with brief information about the file. I also need to include the entire file content **Update (attachment)**, what should be ideal way to do this.

This is what I tried (test code)

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Simon\\csmclientbenz.xml"))
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]

try {
    for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
        System.out.write(buffer, 0, length)
    }
} finally {
    input.close()
}
```

but currently it only prints part of the file. The xml file can be as large as 6MB. What is it that I am missing? Thanks

**Update**

Sending mail code

```
public void sendMail(mailProp,mailData)
{       
    logger.debug("sendMail method")

    Properties properties = System.getProperties()
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", mailProp.host)
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties)

    try{

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session)
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailProp.from))
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(mailProp.to))
        message.setSubject("Configuration failed to upload for simon@abc.com")
        message.setContent(createMessage(mailData), "text/html")
        Transport.send(message)
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....")
    }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code about sending an email... if that's not part of the question, please edit the title to remove the reference.

Comment: @Jim: Hi I updated question with my send mail code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As xml file can be huge upto 6 MB, sending entire file contents in message of email is not a good idea, its better to send as an email attachment. You may refer http://www.roseindia.net/javamail/SendAttachment.shtml to check how to send an attahcment while sending email.

Even better you can compress this xml file before sending it as an attachment to reduce the attachment size using the zip uitlities of java (Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)

Comment: The body of the message content type should be `html`, what shall I use in the [this link](http://www.roseindia.net/javamail/SendAttachment.shtml) to store the body part as html?

Comment: Thanks I am able to send file as an attachment, but the content (Html) does not get rendered, instead I get the whole Html tag as my content in mail body

Comment: You have set html content in text type of email. instead send an html type of email. Here is the link to send all different 3 types of emails: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Comment: In the link that you provided for html `.setContent("<h1>hi</h1>","text/html")` and for multipart `.setContent(multipart)` So how can I have mail content as html along with the attachment file?

Comment: We can set content type in MimeBodyPart too. here is the example:     messageBodyPart.setContent("<h1>hello</h1>","text/html");

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Simon\\csmclientbenz.xml"))));

String line = null;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line)
}
```